# Second camera not detected by opencv in python

Tags: python, windows, opencv, camera

I have 2 identical ELP USB 3.0 cameras. I'm trying to get both working with opencv/python on Windows 10, but only one of the connected cameras ever returns an image. Specifically, using code like the following:

```
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

while True:
    ret, img = cam.read()
    if not ret:
        print('Capture failed')
        break
    cv2.imshow('test', img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if k == ord('k'):
        break
    
cam.release()
```

only shows a video if I use 1 in `cv2.VideoCapture(1)`. Looping through different camera numbers (0-500) and printing the return value of a `camera.read()` only shows True on camera number 1. In other words, opencv does not seem to see the second camera at all. I tested the cameras individually using the Windows "Camera" program, and can successfully swap between the two cameras there, so both work. Also, I've tested the cameras previously on a different Linux machine, and they also both worked with opencv (though not simultaneously, which is a totally different issue) as cameras 0 and 1. Does anyone know what might be wrong?

Comment: The cameras should not be used by other programs. The following code should work normally, assuming that you have also an integrated camera #0. `cam1 = cv.VideoCapture(1); cam2 = cv.VideoCapture(2); assert cam1.isOpened() and cam2.isOpened()`

Comment: In the above code, I tried adding assert `cam.isOpened()` right after cam assignment. Now, if I try using camera number 1, everything works, camera 0, it returns "capture failed", and anything else returns an assertion error. So camera 0 exists but can't capture images?

Comment: Yes, it seems so. Can you try these operations on `cmd`? It should print WARN messages when there is a problem. If not, then try for printing debug messages. I tried creating `cap` while the camera was open by Windows program. It returns true for `cap.isOpened()`, but warns when I try to `read` even after closing Windows Camera program. After `cap.release(); cap.open(0)`, `ret, img = cap.read()` worked.

Comment: When opening cam1 (camera 0) in a python shell, I get a warning when reading: `[ WARN:1] global C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-kh7iq4w7\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (912) CvCapture_MSMF::grabFrame videoio(MSMF): can't grab frame. Error: -2147483638`. If I release, then open, then read, I still get the same error. Open does return true though. I will now try disconnecting each camera in turn and opening camera 0 for each one to see what happens.

Comment: I can confirm that one of the cameras only opens with opencv, but cannot grab a frame. The other camera works fine. The non-working camera works just fine with the "Camera" app on Windows though. Unfortunately I don't have a third camera of the same kind to test.

Comment: I managed to test the two cameras on a different machine with Linux and they both work with opencv. Therefore this seems like a compatibility issue between the cameras and Windows. Strange though that one works fine.